# Adding appSettings section to web.config through c# code

Tags: c#, .net, web-config

I'm just reading the web.config file through this code as

```
Configuration configuration = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");

AppSettingsSection appSettingsSection = (AppSettingsSection)configuration.GetSection("appSettings");

if (appSettingsSection != null)
{
         appSettingsSection.Settings.Remove(key);
         config.Save();
}
```

It works fine when `appSettings` is present in the `web.config` file.

My query is to add `appSettings` tag in `web.config` file if it is not present.

Comment: typically you would simply edit the config file. why are you trying to modify it problematically?

Comment: @Jason Meckley its my work what to do

Answer (score 1):

Here I am adding new application key "myKey" with value "myValue":

```
        System.Configuration.KeyValueConfigurationCollection settings;
        System.Configuration.Configuration config;

        System.Configuration.ExeConfigurationFileMap configFile = new System.Configuration.ExeConfigurationFileMap();
        configFile.ExeConfigFilename = "App.config";
        config = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configFile, System.Configuration.ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        settings = config.AppSettings.Settings;

        config.AppSettings.Settings.Add(new System.Configuration.KeyValueConfigurationElement("myKey", "myValue"));
        config.Save();
```

So the point is to load specific config (add appSettings in you wish), add new keys and save it.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You can check if your `web.config` has `appSettings` tag or not like this;

```
string s = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["appSettings"];

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
{
    // Key exists
}
else
{
    // Key doesn't exist
}
```

I couldn't find anything adding dynamically `appSettings` tag but found three-part series about .NET configuration that could be quite usefull.

- [Unraveling the mysteries of .NET 2.0 configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration.aspx)
- [Decoding the mysteries of .NET 2.0 configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration2.aspx)
- [Cracking the mysteries of .NET 2.0 configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration3.aspx)

Comment: its k how can we add appsettings tag to it